# No internet from the ethernet (and sometimes wi-fi) ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, internet, ethernet

half a year ago I installed this version of Ubuntu alongside with the existing Windows 10. Everything was OK, but several weeks ago it sometimes didn't want me to give an access to the Internet from the ethernet cable or from the wi-fi. Now, when I connect my computer with this cable, it doesn't even recognise it at all. There was even a time when nothing worked and the only access I had was through the Bluetooth. I tried this:

```
sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

and it said: "Cannot find device "eth0"". However, when I passed :

```
dmesg | grep r8169
```

there was no feedback from the Terminal. Is there still any way to fix the Internet issues?

One more thing: I once created a hotspot from my computer and the Ethernet stopped working properly forever while I had been using this hotspot for several days in a row (I don't know if it would somehow help, but still...)

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

gives me:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.2
       version: 0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:61404000-61404fff memory:61400000-61403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: c4
       serial: 84:a6:c8:87:e0:c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.2.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:31 memory:61500000-61501fff
```

Also

```
lspci
```

gives me:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

and there's nothing blocked when using this command:

```
rfkill list all
```

**UPD:**
OK, it turned out that my eth0 was renamed into eno1.

Comment: Launched Windows and everything works fine here, but Ubuntu still doesn't see any Ethernet connection

Comment: Is your Ethernet interface actually named eth0 ? Ubuntu switched to systemd, so naming schemes changed. Run `ip add` or `ifconfig` to make sure

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r8169`

Comment: @chili555,

`[ 2950.896285] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded \n
    [ 2950.896296] r8169 0000:07:00.2: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't     have ASPM control \n
    [ 2950.897200] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: RTL8411 at     0xffffc90001ee0000, 84:34:97:19:c1:51, XID 08800800 IRQ 33 \n 
    [ 2950.897204] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: jumbo features [frames:     9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko] \n
    [ 2950.901642] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eno1: renamed from eth0 \n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @chili555, I found out that my port was renamed from `eth0` to `eno1`. The command I was proposed to parse was:

```
sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r8169
```

Now Ethernet works, although I don't know if Wi-fi is still denying to connect to some spots.